# TFX runs out of memory on 32GB of RAM with only a 232.9MB TFRecord file. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tfx

I am trying to train a model that detects whether someone is using sunglasses using tfx and a subset of the celebsA dataset (~ 26k images). I have written the images and labels to a TFrecord that is 232.9MB.

When I then go through the different components, I always run out of memory when running the Transform component. Is this normal? By the way, I am running this on a TPU with 32GB of RAM as I am using Google Colab Pro.

If so, what would be the best way to overcome the problem? Just create many smaller records and pass them through the components one by one?

Here is the code I have been using:

Code for writing to TFRecord:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import shutil
import random
import os
import io



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

%cd gdrive/MyDrive/Machine_Learning_stuff/celebs/


RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR='./sunglasses_classifier/sunglasses_imgs/raw/'
SUNGLASSES_TFRECORD_DIR= './sunglasses_classifier/data/rec_sunglasses/sunglasses_full.tfrecords'


def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
  if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
    value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
  """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
  """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def image_resize_to_byte_array(image:Image):
  imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
  image=image.resize((256,256))
  image.save(imgByteArr, format="jpeg")
  imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
  return imgByteArr



#Remove any corrupted files and non jpeg files

!find ${RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR} -size 0 -exec rm {} +
!find ${RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR} -type f ! -name "*.jpg" -exec rm {} +

image_labels={}

for filename in os.listdir(RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR + '1-sunglasses'):
  if '.jpg' in filename:
    file_path=os.path.join(RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR,'1-sunglasses',filename)
    #print(file_path)
    image_labels[file_path]=1

for filename in os.listdir(RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR + 'no_sunglasses'):
  if '.jpg' in filename:
    file_path=os.path.join(RAW_SUNGLASSES_DIR,'no_sunglasses',filename)
    #print(file_path)
    image_labels[file_path]=0
  
# Create a dictionary with features that are relevant.
def image_example(image_string, label):
  image_shape = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image_string).shape

  feature = {
      'label': _int64_feature(label),
      'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_string),
  }

  return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(SUNGLASSES_TFRECORD_DIR) as writer:
  for filepath, label in image_labels.items():
    image_bytes=image_resize_to_byte_array(Image.open(filepath,mode='r'))
    #image_string = open(filepath, 'rb').read()
    tf_example = image_example(image_bytes, label)
    writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

Code for TFX pipeline:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
#import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import os
import pprint

#import tfx

from tfx.components import ImportExampleGen
from tfx.components import ExampleValidator
from tfx.components import SchemaGen
from tfx.components import StatisticsGen
from tfx.components import Transform
from tfx.components import Tuner
from tfx.components import Trainer

from tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2
from tfx.orchestration.experimental.interactive.interactive_context import InteractiveContext

# Location of the pipeline metadata store
_pipeline_root = 'pipeline/'

# Directory of the raw data files
_data_root = './data/rec_sunglasses/'

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

%cd gdrive/MyDrive/Machine_Learning_stuff/celebs/sunglasses_classifier/

context = InteractiveContext(pipeline_root=_pipeline_root)

#ExampleGen

example_gen = ImportExampleGen(input_base=_data_root)
context.run(example_gen)

#StatisticsGen
statistics_gen = StatisticsGen(examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'])
context.run(statistics_gen)

#SchemaGen
schema_gen = SchemaGen(
      statistics=statistics_gen.outputs['statistics'],infer_feature_shape=True)
context.run(schema_gen)

#ExampleValidator
example_validator = ExampleValidator(
    statistics=statistics_gen.outputs['statistics'],
    schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'])
context.run(example_validator)

#Transform

_transform_module_file = 'sunglasses_transform.py'

%%writefile {_transform_module_file}

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft

# Keys
_LABEL_KEY = "label"
_IMAGE_KEY = "image_raw"



def _transformed_name(key):
    return key + '_xf'

def _image_parser(image_str):
    '''converts the images to a float tensor'''
    
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_str,channels=3)
    image = tf.reshape(image, (256, 256, 3))
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    return image


def _label_parser(label_id):
    '''converts the labels to a float tensor'''
    label = tf.cast(label_id, tf.float32)
    return label


def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    """tf.transform's callback function for preprocessing inputs.
    Args:
        inputs: map from feature keys to raw not-yet-transformed features.
    Returns:
        Map from string feature key to transformed feature operations.
    """
    
    # Convert the raw image and labels to a float array
    #print(inputs)
    
    outputs = {
        _transformed_name(_IMAGE_KEY):
            tf.map_fn(
                _image_parser,
                tf.squeeze(inputs[_IMAGE_KEY], axis=1),
                dtype=tf.float32),
        _transformed_name(_LABEL_KEY):
            tf.map_fn(
                _label_parser,
                inputs[_LABEL_KEY],
                dtype=tf.float32)
    }

    # scale the pixels from 0 to 1
    outputs[_transformed_name(_IMAGE_KEY)] = tft.scale_to_0_1(outputs[_transformed_name(_IMAGE_KEY)])
    
    return outputs
```

When I then run the code below I always get a message after about 23 mins stating that my runtime was restarted because I ran out of RAM.

```
# Ignore TF warning messages
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

# Setup the Transform component
transform = Transform(
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'],
    schema=schema_gen.outputs['schema'],
    module_file=os.path.abspath(_transform_module_file))

# Run the component
context.run(transform)
```

Comment: As per [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/2764#issuecomment-799573945), it might be introduced due to reshuffling happening in `ExampleGen` which could have caused `OOM` errors when using direct runner. You can take a look at [this workaround](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/issues/143#issuecomment-610260616) proposed to patch this and also you can follow up the Github issue for more details related to the similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bug is in `Transform` itself, as I am encountering an OOM issue passing it a `preprocessing_fn` but do not encounter the same issue when passing the same `preprocessing_fn` to the function below.  Secondly, I face the OOM issue even when just having a training split.  In the case where you are using `Transform`, isn't the beam code essentially abstracted from you, so how can you override what it is doing?  I see the only solution here to not use `Transform` and use something like the below, the downside being that you lose all the `MLMetadata` and `pipeline` benefits, which are significant :(:

```
def transform_data(preprocessing_fn, source_path, source_tfrecord_prefix , experiment_path):
    schema = get_schema_from_transform(source_path)                             
    source_tfrecord_path = f"{source_path}/tfrecords/{source_tfrecord_prefix}*"                                                                     
    with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:                                           
        with tft_beam.Context(temp_dir=tempfile.mkdtemp()):                     
            tfrecord_tfxio = tfxio.TFExampleRecord(                             
                file_pattern=source_tfrecord_path , schema=schema)              
            raw_data = (                                                        
                pipeline | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromTFRecord(              
                    file_pattern=source_tfrecord_path, coder=beam.coders.BytesCoder())
                | 'DecodeTrainData' >> tfrecord_tfxio.BeamSource())             
            raw_dataset = (raw_data, tfrecord_tfxio.TensorAdapterConfig())      
            transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (                               
                raw_dataset | tft_beam.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(              
                    preprocessing_fn, output_record_batches=True))              
            transformed_data, _ = transformed_dataset                           
            transform_fn_output = os.path.join(experiment_path, 'transform_output')
            tfrecord_file_path_prefix = os.path.join(experiment_path, 'tfrecords', experiment_path)
            data_written = (                                                    
                transformed_data | 'EncodeTrainData' >> beam.FlatMapTuple(      
                    lambda batch, _: RecordBatchToExamples(batch)) | beam.io.WriteToTFRecord(
                        tfrecord_file_path_prefix, ))                           
            _ = (transform_fn | 'WriteTransformFn' >> tft_beam.WriteTransformFn(transform_fn_output))
```

My code that generates the OOM is as follows:

```
from tfx import v1 as tfx                                                       
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv                                       
TRAIN_DATA = 'train_smallest.csv'
LABEL_NAME = 'fare_amount'                                                      
BATCH_SIZE=256                                                                  
                                                                                
ORIGINAL_TFRECORD_PATH='./identity_transform/tfrecords/'                                                                    
from tfx.components import ImportExampleGen                                     
from tfx.components import StatisticsGen                                        
from tfx.components import SchemaGen                                            
from tfx.components import Transform                                            
from tfx.v1 import proto                                                        
from tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2                                           
                                                                                
output = proto.Output(                                                          
             split_config=example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(splits=[                  
                 proto.SplitConfig.Split(name='train', hash_buckets=3),         
                 proto.SplitConfig.Split(name='eval', hash_buckets=1)           
             ]))                                                                
example_gen = ImportExampleGen(input_base=ORIGINAL_TFRECORD_PATH, output_config=output)
stats_options = tfdv.StatsOptions(label_feature=LABEL_NAME)                     
statistics_gen = StatisticsGen(examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'], stats_options=stats_options)
schema_gen = SchemaGen(                                                         
      statistics=statistics_gen.outputs['statistics'], infer_feature_shape=True)
transform = Transform(examples = example_gen.outputs['examples'], schema = schema_gen.outputs['schema'], module_file='./preprocessing_fn.py')
components = [                                                                  
      example_gen,                                                              
      statistics_gen,                                                           
      schema_gen,                                                               
      transform                                                                 
  ]                                                                             
                                                                                
pipeline_name='pipeline'                                                        
pipeline_root='./pipeline'                                                      
metadata_path='./metadata/pipeline/metadata.db'                                 
pipeline = tfx.dsl.Pipeline(                                                    
      pipeline_name=pipeline_name,                                              
      pipeline_root=pipeline_root,                                              
      metadata_connection_config=tfx.orchestration.metadata                     
      .sqlite_metadata_connection_config(metadata_path),                        
      components=components,                                                    
enable_cache=False)                                                             
tfx.orchestration.LocalDagRunner().run(pipeline)
```

My `preprocessing_fn` is:

```
import tensorflow as tf                                                         
import tensorflow_addons as tfa                                                 
import tensorflow_transform as tft                                              
NBUCKETS = 10                                                                   
                                                                                
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):                                                   
    """                                                                         
    Preprocess input columns into transformed features. This is what goes       
    into tensorflow transform/apache beam.                                      
    """                                                                         
    # Since we are modifying some features and leaving others unchanged, we     
    # start by setting `outputs` to a copy of `inputs.                          
    transformed = inputs.copy()                                                 
    del(transformed["key"])                                                     
    transformed['passenger_count'] = tft.scale_to_0_1(                          
        inputs['passenger_count'])                                              
    # cannot use the below in tft as managing those learned values need         
    # to be                                                                     
    # managed carefully                                                         
    # normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=None,                     
    # name="passenger_count_normalizer")                                        
    # normalizer.adapt(inputs['passenger_count'])                               
    # transformed['other_passenger_count'] = normalizer(                        
    #               inputs['passenger_count'])                                  
    for col in ['dropoff_longitude', 'dropoff_latitude']:                       
        transformed[col] = tft.sparse_tensor_to_dense_with_shape(inputs[col], default_value=tft.mean(inputs[col]), shape=[None, 1]) #You can make this more robust by using the shape from the feature spec
    for lon_col in ['pickup_longitude', 'dropoff_longitude']:                   
        # transformed[lon_col] = scale_longitude(inputs[lon_col])               
        transformed[lon_col] = (transformed[lon_col] + 78) / 8.                 
    for lat_col in ['pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude']:                     
        transformed[lat_col] = (transformed[lat_col] - 37) / 8.                 
    position_difference = tf.square(                                            
        transformed["dropoff_longitude"] -                                      
        transformed["pickup_longitude"])                                        
    position_difference += tf.square(                                           
        transformed["dropoff_latitude"] -                                       
        transformed["pickup_latitude"])                                         
    transformed['euclidean'] = tf.sqrt(position_difference)                     
    lat_lon_buckets = [                                                         
        bin_edge / NBUCKETS                                                     
        for bin_edge in range(0, NBUCKETS)]                                     
                                                                                
    transformed['bucketed_pickup_longitude'] = tft.apply_buckets(               
        transformed["pickup_longitude"],                                        
        bucket_boundaries=tf.constant([lat_lon_buckets]))                       
    transformed["bucketed_pickup_latitude"] = tft.apply_buckets(                
        transformed['pickup_latitude'],                                         
        bucket_boundaries=tf.constant([lat_lon_buckets]))                       
                                                                                
    transformed['bucketed_dropoff_longitude'] = tft.apply_buckets(              
        transformed["dropoff_longitude"],                                       
        bucket_boundaries=tf.constant([lat_lon_buckets]))                       
    transformed['bucketed_dropoff_latitude'] = tft.apply_buckets(               
        transformed["dropoff_latitude"],                                        
        bucket_boundaries=tf.constant([lat_lon_buckets]))                       
                                                                                
    # transformed["pickup_cross"]=tf.sparse.cross(                              
    # inputs=[transformed['pickup_latitude_apply_buckets'],                     
    # transformed['pickup_longitude_apply_buckets']])                           
    hash_pickup_crossing_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='one_hot', num_bins=NBUCKETS**2, name='hash_pickup_crossing_layer')
    transformed['pickup_location'] = hash_pickup_crossing_layer(                
        (transformed['bucketed_pickup_latitude'],                               
         transformed['bucketed_pickup_longitude']))                             
    hash_dropoff_crossing_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='one_hot', num_bins=NBUCKETS**2,                            
        name='hash_dropoff_crossing_layer')                                     
    transformed['dropoff_location'] = hash_dropoff_crossing_layer(              
        (transformed['bucketed_dropoff_latitude'],                              
         transformed['bucketed_dropoff_longitude']))                            
hash_pickup_crossing_layer_intermediary = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='int', num_bins=NBUCKETS**2, )                              
    hashed_pickup_intermediary = hash_pickup_crossing_layer_intermediary(       
        (transformed['bucketed_pickup_longitude'],                              
         transformed['bucketed_pickup_latitude']))                              
    hash_dropoff_crossing_layer_intermediary = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='int', num_bins=NBUCKETS**2, )                              
    hashed_dropoff_intermediary = hash_dropoff_crossing_layer_intermediary(     
        (transformed['bucketed_dropoff_longitude'],                             
         transformed['bucketed_dropoff_latitude']))                             
                                                                                
    hash_trip_crossing_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='one_hot', num_bins=NBUCKETS ** 3,                          
        name="hash_trip_crossing_layer")                                        
    transformed['hashed_trip'] = hash_trip_crossing_layer(                      
        (hashed_pickup_intermediary,                                            
         hashed_dropoff_intermediary))                                          
                                                                                
    seconds_since_1970 = tf.cast(                                               
        tfa.text.parse_time(                                                    
            inputs["pickup_datetime"],                                          
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z",                                             
            output_unit="SECOND"),                                              
        tf.float32)                                                             
                                                                                
    # seconds_since_1970 = fn_seconds_since_1970(inputs['pickup_datetime'])     
    seconds_since_1970 = tf.cast(seconds_since_1970, tf.float32)                
    hours_since_1970 = seconds_since_1970 / 3600.                               
    hours_since_1970 = tf.floor(hours_since_1970)                               
    hour_of_day_intermediary = hours_since_1970 % 24                            
    transformed['hour_of_day'] = hour_of_day_intermediary                       
    hour_of_day_intermediary = tf.cast(hour_of_day_intermediary, tf.int32)      
    days_since_1970 = seconds_since_1970 / (3600 * 24)                          
    days_since_1970 = tf.floor(days_since_1970)                                 
    # January 1st 1970 was a Thursday                                           
    day_of_week_intermediary = (days_since_1970 + 4) % 7                        
    transformed['day_of_week'] = day_of_week_intermediary                       
    day_of_week_intermediary = tf.cast(day_of_week_intermediary, tf.int32)      
    hashed_crossing_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        num_bins=24 * 7, output_mode="one_hot")                                 
    hashed_crossing_layer_intermediary = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        num_bins=24 * 7, output_mode="int", name='hashed_hour_of_day_of_week_layer')
    transformed['hour_of_day_of_week'] = hashed_crossing_layer(                 
        (hour_of_day_intermediary, day_of_week_intermediary))                   
    hour_of_day_of_week_intermediary = hashed_crossing_layer_intermediary(      
        (hour_of_day_intermediary, day_of_week_intermediary))                   
                                                                                
    hash_trip_crossing_layer_intermediary = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='int', num_bins=NBUCKETS ** 3)                              
    hashed_trip_intermediary = hash_trip_crossing_layer_intermediary(           
        (hashed_pickup_intermediary, hashed_dropoff_intermediary))              
                                                                                
    hash_trip_and_time_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.HashedCrossing(
        output_mode='one_hot', num_bins=(                                       
            NBUCKETS ** 3) * 4, name='hash_trip_and_time_layer')                
    transformed['hashed_trip_and_time'] = hash_trip_and_time_layer(             
        (hashed_trip_intermediary, hour_of_day_of_week_intermediary))           
    return transformed
```

And the data that I'm using is as follows, this is before putting it into tfrecords by using a `preprocessing_fn` that is essentially `f(x) = x`:

```
key,fare_amount,pickup_datetime,pickup_longitude,pickup_latitude,dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude,passenger_count
2010-10-19 00:01:17.0000003,11.3,2010-10-19 00:01:17 UTC,-73.948724,40.777489,-73.949569,40.814049,1
2009-08-19 08:58:00.00000031,8.5,2009-08-19 08:58:00 UTC,-74.007743,40.724717,-74.006797,40.751253,1
2011-01-24 06:48:12.0000001,10.9,2011-01-24 06:48:12 UTC,-73.986678,40.742597,-73.955101,40.766174,1
2014-09-13 09:08:00.000000126,15.5,2014-09-13 09:08:00 UTC,-74.00325,40.7083,-73.975935,40.749007,1
2013-04-12 19:12:22.0000002,10,2013-04-12 19:12:22 UTC,-74.005318,40.728261,-73.981724,40.7293,1
2015-03-11 11:09:40.0000003,13,2015-03-11 11:09:40 UTC,-73.998809814453125,40.734573364257812,-73.989830017089844,40.756542205810547,1
2014-02-26 01:06:40.0000001,8,2014-02-26 01:06:40 UTC,-73.985821,40.763299,-74.003947,40.751722,1
2011-12-03 02:34:21.0000002,15.7,2011-12-03 02:34:21 UTC,-73.940638,40.840057,-73.98792,40.768815,2
2012-12-10 15:50:03.0000002,34,2012-12-10 15:50:03 UTC,-73.872871,40.774284,-73.995264,40.739349,1
2013-09-22 21:15:18.0000001,7.5,2013-09-22 21:15:18 UTC,-73.996565,40.718924,-74.007011,40.707672,2
2011-06-13 20:19:00.00000010,8.1,2011-06-13 20:19:00 UTC,-73.981587,40.747238,-73.956932,40.771512,5
2013-04-13 02:28:55.0000006,4,2013-04-13 02:28:55 UTC,0,0,0,0,1
2013-09-08 15:49:49.0000001,5.5,2013-09-08 15:49:49 UTC,-73.96077,40.775805,-73.970084,40.76252,1
2011-10-05 21:59:00.00000098,6.5,2011-10-05 21:59:00 UTC,-74.005052,40.70663,-74.012255,40.718838,1
2014-10-03 04:04:00.00000020,5.5,2014-10-03 04:04:00 UTC,-74.000032,40.732362,-73.99655,40.736532,5
2010-06-18 13:41:28.0000001,12.1,2010-06-18 13:41:28 UTC,-73.998732,40.717089,-73.975146,40.758038,3
2014-08-07 12:06:50.0000001,13,2014-08-07 12:06:50 UTC,-74.008268,40.722489,-73.982861,40.744874,1
2009-08-30 11:56:58.0000005,5.7,2009-08-30 11:56:58 UTC,-74.007583,40.748017,-73.994615,40.751834,1
2012-01-28 01:58:00.000000132,9.7,2012-01-28 01:58:00 UTC,-74.422832,40.84662,-74.49563,40.968122,1
2012-06-01 13:33:00.00000070,6.9,2012-06-01 13:33:00 UTC,-73.987377,40.743832,-73.998615,40.739855,1
2014-07-31 20:00:00.000000140,14.5,2014-07-31 20:00:00 UTC,-73.983415,40.75677,-73.95324,40.77148,1
2009-02-06 09:25:00.000000128,6.9,2009-02-06 09:25:00 UTC,-73.994222,40.727137,-73.987398,40.744425,1
2012-01-07 20:28:30.0000003,6.9,2012-01-07 20:28:30 UTC,-73.9889,40.7591,-74.0053,40.7401,0
2012-06-13 15:57:00.000000105,8.5,2012-06-13 15:57:00 UTC,-73.982535,40.761602,-73.980302,40.748475,1
2014-05-02 10:33:00.00000042,5,2014-05-02 10:33:00 UTC,-73.985352,40.74213,-73.991562,40.742512,1
2013-03-30 00:33:00.000000133,15,2013-03-30 00:33:00 UTC,-73.98616,40.757022,-74.009022,40.707857,1
2011-05-20 23:01:00.00000071,9.3,2011-05-20 23:01:00 UTC,-73.951177,40.77465,-73.972487,40.743393,1
2011-01-27 21:51:00.000000171,8.9,2011-01-27 21:51:00 UTC,-73.989867,40.756748,-73.972143,40.786588,3
2009-03-20 12:46:25.0000001,6.9,2009-03-20 12:46:25 UTC,-73.951526,40.770003,-73.970998,40.754989,1
2013-05-01 09:32:00.000000143,7,2013-05-01 09:32:00 UTC,-73.990302,40.756552,-73.982462,40.760242,5
2010-05-25 10:10:00.00000027,4.9,2010-05-25 10:10:00 UTC,-73.980722,40.779832,-73.971522,40.787518,1
2012-12-18 07:24:00.000000148,6,2012-12-18 07:24:00 UTC,-73.965952,40.776297,-73.950533,40.774467,4
2012-04-18 08:36:00.000000182,7.7,2012-04-18 08:36:00 UTC,-73.98358,40.766182,-73.97922,40.752992,1
2009-05-23 17:11:00.00000092,42.9,2009-05-23 17:11:00 UTC,-73.781909,40.64477,-73.991234,40.687251,2
2013-04-16 08:44:39.0000006,12,2013-04-16 08:44:39 UTC,-73.961365,40.760555,-73.9805,40.753709,1
2014-04-15 18:39:47.0000002,3.5,2014-04-15 18:39:47 UTC,-74.008172,40.737866,-74.007745,40.732653,1
2013-12-22 17:42:24.0000001,8,2013-12-22 17:42:24 UTC,-73.977505,40.742731,-73.980127,40.722385,2
2011-09-07 20:12:37.0000004,14.5,2011-09-07 20:12:37 UTC,-74.002225,40.715,-73.951187,40.728798,1
2014-12-10 21:57:46.0000005,6.5,2014-12-10 21:57:46 UTC,-73.97175,40.760287,0,0,1
2012-11-12 22:11:00.000000101,6.5,2012-11-12 22:11:00 UTC,-73.983615,40.760325,-73.998885,40.760012,1
2015-02-21 19:26:56.0000005,15,2015-02-21 19:26:56 UTC,-73.9959716796875,40.686809539794922,-74.009872436523438,40.718009948730469,1
2010-10-06 03:28:42.0000001,8.9,2010-10-06 03:28:42 UTC,-73.988341,40.72886,-73.984581,40.751519,1
2010-07-09 22:01:22.0000007,4.1,2010-07-09 22:01:22 UTC,-73.959272,40.771833,-73.962304,40.773124,1
2009-05-28 10:45:00.00000032,8.9,2009-05-28 10:45:00 UTC,-73.988872,40.753367,-73.972733,40.753327,1
2013-09-24 18:25:00.000000123,25,2013-09-24 18:25:00 UTC,-74.005197,40.751602,-73.980317,40.676607,1
2009-02-05 08:23:01.0000004,7.3,2009-02-05 08:23:01 UTC,-73.975468,40.759635,-73.991854,40.749352,1
2011-07-03 22:25:04.0000003,28.5,2011-07-03 22:25:04 UTC,-73.776755,40.64523,-73.951802,40.657781,1
2010-06-07 15:20:00.000000164,17.7,2010-06-07 15:20:00 UTC,-73.969625,40.758133,-74.012548,40.713983,1
2012-09-14 01:02:00.000000106,7,2012-09-14 01:02:00 UTC,-73.982777,40.744722,-73.984505,40.732127,1
2013-03-08 23:16:00.00000051,25.5,2013-03-08 23:16:00 UTC,-73.990822,40.734702,-73.945737,40.651117,1
2009-10-30 16:06:00.00000074,10.1,2009-10-30 16:06:00 UTC,-73.981008,40.768257,-73.968412,40.80144,2
2012-12-13 19:08:47.0000004,4.5,2012-12-13 19:08:47 UTC,-73.949347,40.78134,-73.956487,40.777995,1
2009-09-03 18:08:00.000000222,5.3,2009-09-03 18:08:00 UTC,-73.985702,40.753625,-73.989385,40.741143,5
2014-05-09 14:18:00.00000085,22.5,2014-05-09 14:18:00 UTC,-73.994697,40.765992,-74.012857,40.706807,1
2010-06-13 18:07:00.00000026,5.7,2010-06-13 18:07:00 UTC,-73.98811,40.774712,-73.98207,40.763285,1
2009-05-30 22:44:00.0000003,15.7,2009-05-30 22:44:00 UTC,-73.968862,40.791558,-73.971705,40.793732,2
2009-05-03 09:58:47.0000002,3.7,2009-05-03 09:58:47 UTC,-73.966445,40.804635,-73.969422,40.798094,1
2011-02-21 22:48:57.0000004,5.7,2011-02-21 22:48:57 UTC,-73.977624,40.752278,-73.994179,40.751649,1
2009-01-09 22:16:00.00000018,4.5,2009-01-09 22:16:00 UTC,-73.961832,40.763897,-73.96975,40.759523,1
2011-06-17 10:31:00.000000154,7.3,2011-06-17 10:31:00 UTC,-73.963242,40.771425,-73.968752,40.7537,1
2014-11-24 12:38:00.000000143,5,2014-11-24 12:38:00 UTC,-73.969662,40.753422,-73.975425,40.74545,1
2015-05-03 09:46:20.0000007,14.5,2015-05-03 09:46:20 UTC,-73.9213638305664,40.745254516601562,-73.85888671875,40.751045227050781,2
2010-04-05 18:49:28.0000001,8.9,2010-04-05 18:49:28 UTC,-73.960298,40.766187,-73.981875,40.727677,1
2013-12-17 20:12:00.00000030,6.5,2013-12-17 20:12:00 UTC,-73.956007,40.779077,-73.965855,40.765742,1
2010-03-12 21:29:00.000000235,9.3,2010-03-12 21:29:00 UTC,0,0,0,0,3
2011-11-30 17:09:00.000000158,14.1,2011-11-30 17:09:00 UTC,-73.985565,40.731717,-73.981347,40.77369,1
2011-12-18 22:21:00.000000162,12.1,2011-12-18 22:21:00 UTC,-73.995165,40.753117,-73.98827,40.725642,1
2010-09-02 14:39:00.000000201,4.1,2010-09-02 14:39:00 UTC,-73.978898,40.785037,-73.970818,40.789267,1
2014-08-22 16:00:00.00000098,6,2014-08-22 16:00:00 UTC,-73.97484,40.756925,-73.972712,40.761775,3
```

@tensorflow-support let's solve this issue and make `Transform` and `LocalDagRunner` usable so people can solve cool problems with it!

Comment: I did some more digging, and it appears that the behavior of the hashed crossing layer is the culprit. 
 More details at https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/different-behavior-of-tf-keras-layers-experimental-preprocessing-hashedcrossing/14366